# How can I match a dataframe's rows in python, creating a new column based on correct matching?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Working in python with a dataframe, I'm trying to match certain rows and create a new column based on successful matching - e.g. if 'Breed' + 'Color' match, put 'Name' of matched row in 'Mate' column of the Male in the pair. For example, in the table below Adam/Eve and Antony/Cleopatra should be matched, resulting in Eve and Cleopatra being put in the 'Mate' column for Adam and Antony, respectively. Since Clyde and Beauty have different breeds, this does not occur.

| Name | Breed | Color | Sex | Mate? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Boxer | White | Male | (Eve) |
| Eve | Boxer | White | Female |  |
| Antony | Lab | Chocolate | Male | (Cleopatra) |
| Cleopatra | Lab | Chocolate | Female |  |
| Clyde | Husky | Gray | Male |  |
| Beauty | Bulldog | Gray | Female |  |

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# First collect the Potential names of mates
mates = defaultdict(list)
for row in df.itertuples():
    props = (row.Breed, row.Color)
    mates[props].append(row.Name)

# Secondly create Mate column
def return_mates(name, breed, color):
    match = (breed, color)
    return [m for m in mates[match] if m != name]

df.loc[:, 'Mate'] = df[['Name', 'Breed', 'Color']].apply(lambda x: return_mates(*x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
df['Mate?'] = df.Name.map(dict(df.groupby(['Breed', 'Color'])['Name'].agg(list).apply(pd.Series).dropna().values)).fillna('')
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
        Name    Breed      Color     Sex      Mate?
0       Adam    Boxer      White    Male        Eve
1        Eve    Boxer      White  Female           
2     Antony      Lab  Chocolate    Male  Cleopatra
3  Cleopatra      Lab  Chocolate  Female           
4      Clyde    Husky       Gray    Male           
5     Beauty  Bulldog       Gray  Female
```